# Do I need a transit visa for a 13 hour stay in Sydney airport?

Tags: transit, australia, filipino-citizens, new-zealand-permanent-resident

I'm a Filipino with a permanent residency here in New Zealand, I noticed that I have a 13 hour stop over in Sydney Australia, from 6:30 AM to 7:30 PM, do I still need to get a transit visa?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external-result/r140GHPAlD5yMwgbrkKshpX4pghI) you will need a transit visa for Australia as you will be at the airport for longer than 8 hours.

> **Australia - Transit Visa**
>
> **Visa required.**
>
> Transiting without a visa is possible for: ...
>   Nationals of Philippines transiting through Cairns (CNS) or **Sydney
>   (SYD)** with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country
>   **within 8 hours** on the same calendar day. They must stay in the
>   international transit area of the airport and have documents required
>   for the next destination...
>
> Additional information: Airlines can verify the status of an
>   electronic visa holder by using Australia's Advance Passenger
>   Processing (APP) system before boarding the aircraft. Verification by
>   airlines using Australia's Advance Passenger Processing (APP) system
>   will require the details of the travel document that the visa is
>   issued against.